# How to prevent DependencyCycle?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger

After added to refreshToken I get this error. It make problem because of using a method of `AuthsRepository` in `TokenAuthenticator` class. When I removed to using `authsRepository` that's not make problem. How can I solve it? Can I use this method in `TokenAuthenticator`?. I need any help like suggest any way any solution.

> public abstract interface AppComponent extends
> dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.technoface.chicmen.ChicMenApplication>
> {
> ^
> retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RestModule.provideAuthsService(retrofit)
> com.technoface.data.AuthsService is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RepositoryModule.provideAuthsRepository(authsService)
> com.technoface.data.repository.AuthsRepository is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RetrofitModule.provideTokenAuthenticator(�,
> authsRepository)
> com.technoface.data.TokenAuthenticator is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RetrofitApiModule.provideOkHttpClient(�,
> tokenAuthenticator, �)
> okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RetrofitApiModule.provideRetrofitClient(�,
> client)
> com.technoface.data.RetrofitClient is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RetrofitApiModule.provideRetrofit(retrofitClient)
> retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
> com.technoface.chicmen.RestModule.provideAuthsService(retrofit)
> ...

RetrofitApiModule.kt

```
    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        headerInterceptor: HeaderInterceptor,
        tokenAuthenticator: TokenAuthenticator,
        logger: HttpLoggingInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        builder.authenticator(tokenAuthenticator)
        builder.addInterceptor(logger)
        builder.readTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT_V1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        builder.writeTimeout(WRITE_TIME_OUT_V1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        return builder.build()
    }
}
```

RetrofitModule.kt

```
@Module(
    includes = [
        RetrofitApiModule::class
    ]
)

object RetrofitModule {

    @AppScope
    @REST
    @Provides
    fun provideBaseUrl(): String {
        return BuildConfig.BASE_URL
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideHeaderInterceptor(
        userProvider: UserProviderListener
    ): HeaderInterceptor {
        return HeaderInterceptor(userProvider)
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideTokenAuthenticator(
        tokenInvalidator: TokenInvalidatorListener,
        userProvider: UserProviderListener,
        authsRepository: AuthsRepository
    ): TokenAuthenticator {
        return TokenAuthenticator(tokenInvalidator, userProvider, authsRepository)
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        return logging
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideGson(): Gson {
        return Gson()
    }

}

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class REST
```

RestModule.kt

```
@Module(
    includes = [
        RetrofitModule::class
    ]
)

object RestModule {

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthsService(
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): AuthsService {
        return retrofit.create(AuthsService::class.java)
    }
```

TokenAuthenticator.kt

```
class TokenAuthenticator(
    private val tokenInvalidator: TokenInvalidatorListener,
    private val userProvider: UserProviderListener,
    private val authsRepository: AuthsRepository
) : Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        return if (userProvider.getIsLoginUser()) {
            val refreshResponse = authsRepository.refreshToken().blockingGet().exceptionOrNull()
            if (refreshResponse != null) {
                tokenInvalidator.invalidateUser()
                userProvider.logout()
                return null
            }
            return response.request()
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

}
```

AuthsRepository.kt

```
class AuthsRepository(
    private val authsService: AuthsService
) : Repository {

    fun verifyOtpForgotPassword(request: VerifyOtpForgotPasswordRequest): Single<Result<RestResponse<Any>>> {
        return authsService.verifyOtpForgotPassword(request).map {
            Result.success(it)
        }.onErrorReturn {
            Result.failure(it)
        }
    }

    fun refreshToken(): Single<Result<RestResponse<LoginResponse>>> {
        return authsService.refreshToken().map {
            Result.success(it)
        }.onErrorReturn {
            Result.failure(it)
        }
    }

}
```